# What plug is this/ what adapter do i need?

Tags: electrical, adapter

so i have a lamp but the plug isn’t one i’ve typically seen before so i don't know what adapter i would need. I have done some research and found that type A plug is the closest thing however on a type A plug it seems that one pin is wider than the other and there is also holes. Would be so grateful if anyone could help! [image]

Comment: Your location? where did you buy the lamp? Did they assume a market? Plugs vary around the world. Solution: cut the plug off and fit the standard plug for your location.

Comment: It looks similar to the old type A, but it seems to have a low max rating, 6amp at 250v.

Comment: Probably needs to be sent back to the direct import supplier as a non-listed device, at first guess.

Answer (score 2):

### This is also a Type A (NEMA 1-15P)

This, too, is a Type A plug, or in the US a NEMA 1-15P.  As you see here, for certain appliances (normally those considered *double insulated* under UL standards, but lamps aren't normally double insulated, so I don't know what's going on in your situation), Type A plugs are permitted to lack polarization, and the holes in the prongs are an optional feature as well.

Comment: It depends on the age of the appliance/lamp also.  Polarized plugs are a bit recent safety upgrade.

Comment: @crip659 -- yeah, some very old stuff has unpolarized plugs as well but those usually have two narrow blades, and the plug'd be old too :P